How do I keep WebSocket alive when loading extension via command line?
I have been developing a Chrome extension that uses a WebSocket to communicate with an application on the local machine (via the local loopback interface). However, the WebSocket will randomly close, even if I am transmitting a regular heartbeat signal as advised by this chrome article.
After several days of experimenting and troubleshooting, I found that the strange behavior only occurs when loading the extension using the --load-extension command line argument. If I omit this argument and load the extension manually, then the WebSocket remains open until I close the browser.
I created an MVCE using Eclispe Vert.x. It's a rather large file, but it clearly demonstrates the issue:
public class WebSocketVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path workingDirectory = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")).toAbsolutePath();
        Path extensionDirectory = workingDirectory.resolve("extension");

        // Create unpacked extension
        Files.createDirectories(extensionDirectory);
        Path serviceWorker = extensionDirectory.resolve("background.js");
        try (PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(Files.newOutputStream(serviceWorker, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE))) {
            stream.println("var SESSIONS = {};");
            stream.println("(() => {");
            stream.println("\tconst socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:59132/');");
            stream.println("\tsocket.onmessage = (event) => socket.send('Recieved message: ' + event.data);");
            stream.println("\tsocket.onclose = (_event) => delete SESSIONS['someId'];");
            stream.println("\tSESSIONS['someId'] = socket;");
            stream.println("})();");
            stream.flush();
        }

        Path manifest = extensionDirectory.resolve("manifest.json");
        try (OutputStream stream = Files.newOutputStream(manifest, StandardOpenOption.CREATE,
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
            String json = "{\"name\":\"WebSocket Example\",\"description\":\"Demonstrates WebSocket irregularities when using --load-extension\",\"author\":{\"name\":\"Cardinal System\",\"email\":\"user@example.com\"},\"version\":\"1.0\",\"manifest_version\":3,\"background\":{\"service_worker\":\"background.js\"}}";
            stream.write(json.getBytes());
            stream.flush();
        }

        Path userData = workingDirectory.resolve("data");
        if (Files.isDirectory(userData)) {
            try (Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(userData)) {
                walk.sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder()).map(Path::toFile).forEach(File::delete);
            }
        }

        // Launch HTTP server and Google Chrome
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        try {
            vertx.deployVerticle(new WebSocketVerticle()).toCompletionStage().toCompletableFuture().get();
            runChrome(userData, extensionDirectory);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            vertx.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Promise<Void> startPromise) {
        HttpServer server = this.vertx.createHttpServer();
        server.webSocketHandler(webSocket -> {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            webSocket.handler(b -> System.out.println("Extension: \"" + b.toString() + "\""));
            Thread heartbeat = startHeartbeat(webSocket);

            webSocket.closeHandler(e -> {
                long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println("WebSocket closed: Status code " + webSocket.closeStatusCode());
                System.out.println("Connected for: " + (end - start) + "ms");
                heartbeat.interrupt();
            });
        }).listen(59132).andThen(event -> startPromise.complete());
    }

    private Thread startHeartbeat(ServerWebSocket socket) {
        Thread heartbeat = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    socket.writeTextMessage("Ping");
                    Thread.sleep(20000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException t) {
            }
        });
        heartbeat.start();
        return heartbeat;
    }

    private static void runChrome(Path userData, Path extension) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
        command.add("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
        command.add("--disable-fre");
        command.add("--no-first-run");
        command.add("--no-default-browser-check");
        command.add("--start-maximized");
        command.add("--user-data-dir=" + userData.toString());

        // Comment out the following line to see the WebSocket connection kept alive
        command.add("--load-extension=" + extension.toString());

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}

How do I make the WebSocket stay connected when using --load-extension?
